# TextField On Tap calls initState of background Pages

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter

Following is the example situation:

1. I have four Pages A, B, C, D.
2. Page A, B, C have buttons at the bottom.
3. On Clicking/Tap I can go from A->B->C->D.
4. Page D contains 2 TextFields.
5. On editing text field.
6. initState() of Page A, B, C is called.

How can I restrict this, when I edit `TextField` the `initState()` of the background to be called?

Comment: Can you share more code especially how you are navigating after tapping on buttons?

Comment: I used a unique key for API call that was a problem.